# ooxml-schemas, IntelliJ IDEA, and NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, apache-poi, openxml

I am attempting to use certain functions which require the ooxml-schemas jar and even after importing the poi-ooxml library and the ooxml-schemas library via Maven, I still get a NullPointerException on the 13th line. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class ASM {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("AASM.docx"));
        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
        CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.getPgSz();
        double pageWidth = pageSz.getW().doubleValue();
        CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
        double pageMarginLeft = pageMar.getLeft().doubleValue();
        double pageMarginRight = pageMar.getRight().doubleValue();
        double effectivePageWidth = pageWidth - pageMarginLeft - pageMarginRight;
        //Header
        XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
        XWPFTable headerTable = header.createTable(1, 3);
        CTTblWidth width = headerTable.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblW();
        width.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
        width.setW(new BigInteger(effectivePageWidth + ""));
        XWPFTableRow headerTableRowOne = headerTable.getRow(0);
        //Cell 0
        XWPFTableCell companyCell = headerTableRowOne.getCell(0);
        XWPFParagraph companyParagraph = companyCell.addParagraph();
        XWPFRun companyRun = companyParagraph.createRun();
        InputStream companyImageInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("20opy.png"));
        companyRun.addPicture(companyImageInputStream, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "20opy.png", Units.toEMU(125), Units.toEMU(19));
        //Main Document
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Hello world");
        run.addPicture(companyImageInputStream, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "20opy.png", Units.toEMU(125), Units.toEMU(19));
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `NullPointerException` cannot be caused by missing libraries. A `NPE` occurs if an object points to `NULL` but code tries using that object somehow.

In your case if `sectPr.getPgSz()` throws `NPE`, then `sectPr` is `null` and so `null.getPgSz()` throws `NPE`.

Why `sectPr` is `null`? It is because `document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr()` has returned `null`. And this is to expect since a new created `XWPFDocument` using `XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();` does not have any section properties set. It relies on the defaults of the wordprocessing application when it comes to section and/or page settings.

What is clear is, that you always needs to check whether there are already `CTSectPr` in the document. And you only can using them if they are there already. Else they needs to be created using `addNewSectPr`.

Your intention to get the page settings seems to be to set the table's width to `effectivePageWidth`. But since a new created `XWPFDocument` does not have any section properties set, you need setting them initially first instead trying to get what does not exists.

See examples of code where I have used `CTSectPr`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3915431+CTSectPr+